# Что значит пословица "В мужицком брюхе и долото сгниёт"?

Tags: фразеология

В интернете находится во многих списках пословиц, но не могу найти где истолковывается.

На ум приходят варианты:

- Беднякам нечего есть, что хоть долото ешь;
- У бедняков желудок переварит даже долото;
- Мужик сломает даже долото;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если рассмотреть сборники пословиц и поговорок, то большинство их составителей относят пословицу "В мужицком брюхе и долото сгниёт" в раздел "богатство и бедность":
[**Пословицы и поговорки о богатстве и о бедности**](http://kladraz.ru/poslovicy-i-pogovorki/ruskie-poslovicy-i-pogovorki-pro-bogatstvo-bednost-dlja-detei.html);
[**К.Берсеньева, Русские пословицы и поговорки (богатство, бедность)**](http://www.bookfb2.ru/book57/433886.fb2).

Там же чаще всего располагаются и синонимичные пословицы:
В русском брюхе и долото сгниёт.
В русском животе долото сгниёт.
В русском животе молоток растворится.

*Бывало мясо продавать в город на базар поедет, почнёт его рубить, и ежели хошь махонькая косточка отлетит, чичас её в карман, а ежели мяса куса кусочек, чичас себе в рот. Мужики-то ему: "Ужо пронесёт тя!" А он им: "Ничо, **в русском брюхе и долото сгниёт**".*
**[Еще один сказ моей прапрабабушки Кати](http://www.spletnik.ru/blogs/chto_chitaem/84408_eshce-odin-skaz-moey-praprababushki-kati)**

*— Вношу на мирское дело муки сеяной три мешка да немолотого четыре центнера. Капустка тоже есть, отдаю вместе с дубовой кадушечкой. Боровка я в заговены засолил, да повял малость…

— Ничего, **в мужицком брюхе долото сгниет**. Давай сюды!*
[**Л.Леонов, Лёнушка (народная трагедия в четырех действиях)**](http://www.leonid-leonov.ru/files/lyonushka.fb2)

Получается, что пословица имеет двоякий смысл: и о бедности, и о выносливости именно русского мужика.

Comment: Исходя из примеров подходит вариант "У бедняков желудок переварит даже долото".

Comment: Правильно будет сказать так: осилит желудок бедного русского мужика. Под выносливостью я именно это и подразумевала

Answer (score 1):

Думается, здесь речь о недюжинном природном здоровье и (второе) попытка гиперболического сравнения его со столь же крепким и надёжным инструментом — не экзотическим, а практически обиходным для условного *мужика*. Почему не другой предмет, а долото? Да по той причине, что оно само приспособлено для проделывания (долбления) отверстий, выемок, желобов.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что у мужика такой крепкий желудок, что его и долотом не пробьёшь, вот оно и сгниёт без дела.